# join xml data usng c#

Tags: c#, xml

i will join table 1 and table 2 in xml using c#..Can anyone provide me a c# code to achiev the above scenario?

**Table 1  :**

```
  <REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>1</ID>
<DESCRIP>Sinus</DESCRIP>
<DESCRIP_DTL>- 3 or more continuous beats satisfied with all of the following: 1. Duration QRS &lt; 120 ms or duration QRS = 120 ms and
 - 30 &lt; axis QRS &lt; 150 (QRS(V1) &gt; 0 mV) or
 - 60 &lt; axis QRS &lt; 120 (QRS(V1) = 0 mV) 2. P  wave is normal 3. 120 = interval PR = 200 ms- 60 = HR &lt; 100 bpm</DESCRIP_DTL> 
</REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

 <REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>2</ID>
<DESCRIP>SA Exit Block</DESCRIP>
 </REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
 <REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

<ID>3</ID>
<DESCRIP>Wandering Pacemaker</DESCRIP>
 </REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
```

**Tabel 2  :**

```
  <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>1</ID>
<DESCRIP>Bradikardi</DESCRIP>
 </REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

 <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>2</ID>
<DESCRIP>Takikardi</DESCRIP>
 </REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

 <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>3</ID>
<DESCRIP>Disritmia</DESCRIP>
</REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
```

I need to read the above two xml files and write it into a new xml files with selected elements?

**Output  :**

```
  <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>1</ID>
<DESCRIP>Bradikardi</DESCRIP>
<ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>1</ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<GANGGUAN_IRAMA>Sinus</GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
 </REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

 <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>2</ID>
<DESCRIP>Takikardi</DESCRIP>
<ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>1</ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<GANGGUAN_IRAMA>Sinus</GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
 </REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>

 <REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<ID>3</ID>
<DESCRIP>Disritmia</DESCRIP>
<ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>1</ID_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
<GANGGUAN_IRAMA>Sinus</GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
</REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN_IRAMA>
```

This my code..please correct

**Code  :**

```
  ListItemPopup irm;
    DataSet dsSet = new DataSet();
    dsSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\\Referensi.data");
    DataTable data = dsSet.Tables["REF_GANGGUAN_IRAMA"];
    DataTable data1 = dsSet.Tables["REF_JENIS_GANGGUAN"];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < data1.Rows.Count; j++)
             {
                 irm = new ListItemPopup(data1.Rows[i]["ID"], data1.Rows[i]["DESCRIP"], "");
                 cbjenis.Items.Add(irm);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the path for your question.

1. Read XML file for table 1 and Table 2 Together and find out whether they have same record
2. Then write that into new Xml File.

psuedo code:

```
string paht1=
string path2=
string path3=

load table1.xml
load table2.xml

for ()
{
get first value of table1
   for()
     {
         get relevent value from table 2
         write it in you new xml file
     }

}
```

you must better try on this...

**Edit :**
According to your edit(your tried solution) what is the problem???

anyway use [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) to write it back.

this link will be helpfull for you- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx)